# str_replace() not working for the following case

Tags: php, str-replace, findandmodify

I would like to use `str_replace()` to place span elements around html strings for the purpose of highlighting them.

However the following does not work when there is `&nbsp;` inside the string. I've tried replacing the `&nbsp;` with `' '` but this did not help.

---

**LIVE example**

You can recreate the problem using the below code:

```
$str_to_replace = "as a way to incentivize&nbsp;more purchases.";

$replacement = "<span class='highlighter'>as a way to incentivize&nbsp;more purchases.</span>";

$subject = file_get_contents("http://venturebeat.com/2015/11/10/sources-classpass-raises-30-million-from-google-ventures-and-others/");

$output = str_replace($str_to_replace,$replacement,$subject);

.highlighter{
    background-collor: yellow;
}
```

Comment: if you look at the source of that page there is not a `&nbsp;` where you say there should be

Comment: how is this different than your past dozen questions?

Comment: Change your `&bsnp;` to space

Comment: Change `&nbsp;` to a single space only on `$string_to_replace`. You'll want to keep the other one for output.

Comment: @aldrin27, backspace no problem? big space no period?

Comment: Have you tried the code? It finds the string but doesn't replace it. Click inspect element on the sentence in the example - there is clearly &nbsp;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried your code and ran into the same problem you did. Interesting, right? The problem is that there's actually another character inbetween the "e" in "incentivize" and the " more", you can see it if you do this, split `$subject` into two parts, preceding the text `to incentivize` and after:

```
// splits the webpage into two parts
$x = explode('to incentivize', $subject);

// print the char code for the first character of the second string
// (the character right after the second e in incentivize) and also
// print the rest of the webpage following this mystery character
exit("keycode of invisible character: " . ord($x[1]) . " " . $x[1]);
```

which prints: `keycode of invisible character: 194 Â more ...`, look! There's our mystery character, and it has charcode 194!

Perhaps this website embeds these characters to make it difficult to do exactly what you're doing, or perhaps it's just a bug. In any case, you can use `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace` and change `$str_to_replace` like so:

```
$str_to_replace = "/as a way to incentivize(.*?)more purchases/";

$replacement = "<span class='highlighter'>as a way to incentivize more purchases.</span>";

$subject = file_get_contents("http://venturebeat.com/2015/11/10/sources-classpass-raises-30-million-from-google-ventures-and-others/");

$output = preg_replace($str_to_replace,$replacement,$subject);
```

and now this does what you want. The `(.*?)` handles the mysterious hidden character. You can probably shrink this regular expression even further or at least cap it at a maximum amount of characters `([.]{0,5})` but in either case you likely want to stay flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a much simpler way with this:

```
$subject = str_replace("\xc2\xa0", " ", $subject);
```

Which will replace all `&nbsp;` characters with a standard space.

You can now continue with your code, but replace all your `&nbsp;` with a regular  space